# Html escaping in a Rails 3 view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, xss, erb

I'm using Rails 3. I want to display generated html fragment inside erb template

```
<%= "<div>Foo Bar</div>" %>
```

Rails encodes div tags.

If I'm correct in Rails 2 `<%=h` causes html escaping. Seems that it was changed in Rails 3. How can insert html fragment without encoding in Rails 3?

Regards,
Alexey.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume by encoding you mean the html-escaping:

To put out raw html in Rails 3 you can use three different approaches.

1. your can use the `raw` helper to output raw html

   ```
   <% some_string = "<div>Hello World!</div>" %>
   <%= some_string %>
   <!-- outputs: &lt;div&gt;Hello Worlds!&lt;/div&gt; -->
   <%=raw some_string %>
   <!-- outputs: <div>Hello Worlds!</div> -->
   ```

   more information: [ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper#raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)
2. You can mark the string as `html_safe`

   ```
   <% some_string = "<div>Hello World!</div>".html_safe %>
   <%= some_string %>
   <!-- outputs: <div>Hello World!</div> -->
   ```

   more information: [String#html_safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) and [ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer#new](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html#method-c-new)
3. You can sanitize your output with `sanitize`

   ```
   <%=sanitize "<div>Hello World!</div>", tags: %w( div ) %>
   ```

   more information: [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper#sanitze](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize)

Some more Information:

- [SafeBuffers and Rails 3.0](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/)
- [Railscast #204: XSS Protection in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3)

Comment: This is correct, but I think it's worth noting that often the more safe way to do it is to use `<%= content_tag :div, "Hello World!" %>` That doesn't involve any marking of potentially dangerous strings as safe.

Comment: You are right if the text is as simple as in the example, but I believe the Hello World is an example text for something that the OP has stored in the DB so he can't use `content_tag` because it could also be anything but a `<div/>` containing everything, and there could be any number of html tags within this div. if you take the example, the easiest and also fastest way would be to pass on erb completely and just write `<div>Hello World</div>` outside of any erb tag

Comment: +1 for "raw" if you want a short solution with conditional tag options:
<td<%=raw %/ class="cancelled"/ if ticket.cancelled %>>Ticket number 3</td>

Comment: don't forget about "sanitize", used just like raw, but removes javascript and untrusted content!

Comment: @dtt101 I updated my answer with information about `sanitize`