# How to remove tags from strings in html file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example if my field contains

```
description: "<p>Some Text </p>"
```

and I display it in my html.erb file as `item.description` How can I remove this p tags?

```html
  <div class="preview__text">
          <%= sanitize(item.description) %>
        </div>
```

or

```html
  <div class="preview__text">
          <%= item.description.html_safe %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.html_safe`

```
<%= item.description.html_safe %>
```

Or [sanitize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)

```
<%= sanitize(item.description) %>
```

Comment: Then nothing loads when I try both

Comment: can the description be NIL ? What's the error?

Comment: It just removes everything thats within the `<p>` tag, only what I see is text with `h2`

Comment: Update the question with your erb file, where you call this.

Comment: Oh, are you on rails 3?

Comment: What you have there should work. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573851/html-escaping-in-a-rails-3-view. Those methods are available in rails 3 too, so everything should be fine. Unless your description contents is ... different.

Comment: Ok works now, had to add  `tags: %w(div)` beside sanitize

Answer (score 3):

You can use strip_tags method in ActionView: : Helpers : : SanitizeHelper :

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags